# Is normalizing input graph's node attributes before training GNNs required? How to do it

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, graph-theory, graph-neural-network

I am new in GNN, and I have a dataset of weighted graphs that each node in each graph has the following attributes:

```
{
 'coordinates': [43.22, 12.88],
 'degree': 4892.251,
 'flow_centrality': 25.629,
 'betweenness_centrality': 2.5,
 'load_centrality': 2.0,
 'second_centrality': 137.671,
 'id': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0]
}
```

I have noticed that normalizing/scaling attributes in input graphs is required for GNN as stated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563763/nodes-attribute-scaling-normalization-before-graph-embedding-learning-gnn). My question is that how can I normalize these attributes? Betweenness centrality, and load centrality can be normalized but what about the rest of attributes?

I would appreciate if you have any suggestions for me.

Comment: These seem to be graph metrics, not node attributes.

Comment: Yes, they are graph metrics that we are using as attributes @gunes